# How do I get the current co-ordinates of a Circle/Node during a TranslationTransition Javafx

Tags: javafx

This has been racking by brain for two days now. I've read through the javadocs for node/circle and can't seem to find a solution.

I have made a set of circles and have them grouped as a node.

```
 target = new Group(OuterRingTarget, OuterWhiteRingTarget, MiddleRingTarget, MiddleWhiteRingTarget, InnerRingTarget, BullseyeTarget);
```

I set the sizes and locations in the the animation e.g

```
    OuterRingTarget.setCenterX(200);
    OuterRingTarget.setCenterY(200);
    OuterRingTarget.setRadius(25);

    OuterWhiteRingTarget.setCenterX(200);
    OuterWhiteRingTarget.setCenterY(200);
    OuterWhiteRingTarget.setRadius(22);
    OuterWhiteRingTarget.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
```

etc

I create 4 random numbers (starting x/y and setBy x/y) for the TranslateTransition. For some reason .settoX doesn't work so I had to use setByX.

```
       final TranslateTransition targetAnimation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        targetAnimation.setNode(target);
        targetAnimation.setFromX(x0);
        targetAnimation.setByX(x1);
        targetAnimation.setFromY(y0);
        targetAnimation.setByY(y1);
        targetAnimation.setCycleCount(1);
        targetAnimation.onFinishedProperty().set(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                AnimationTargetStart();
            }
        });
        targetAnimation.play();
```

I need to check when the user clicks, whether the co-ordinates that the user clicked is equal to where the circles are located (i.e that the user has clicked the node). And to do this I need to check where the circles are mid-translationtransition.

Someone suggested a double property on another thread, I tried it, but it didn't work:

```
DoubleProperty xValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    xValue.bind(BullseyeTarget.centerXProperty());
    xValue.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {

        System.out.println(" Current center X: " + (double) arg2);
    }
});
```

I also tried:

```
     double TargetXCentre = BullseyeTarget.getCenterX();
     double TargetYCentre = BullseyeTarget.getCenterY();
```

Which just returned the value that I set earlier, rather than returning the updated value during the transition. Is there a way of setting the .centerX during the transition without moving the shape itself? or getting the current position of the circles/node during the translationtransition.

I'm sure I am overcomplicating things, and that there is a way of setting each circle to have an onclick mouse event to detect hits, so that I don't need to do calculations for a hit, but I'm not sure how to do this either.

Cheers

Lucio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do the coordinate computation: just register a mouse listener with the node you are interested in. I'm not sure exactly what your requirements are, but

```
target.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
    System.out.println("hit target!");
});
```

should do what you want. You can replace `target` with any of the component circles if you need.

If you did want to track coordinates, by the way, you need to know that the translate transition works by manipulating the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of the node that is being animated. These property values are essentially added to the `centerX` and `centerY` properties of the circles (this is something of a simplification, but it will work). The `boundsInParent` property of a node contains the bounds of the node in the coordinate system of its parent node (i.e. the node to whose `getChildren()` list it is added), and accounts for all transformations (including the translation defined by the `translateX` and `translateY` properties). So if you registered a mouse listener with the parent of the `target`, you could do something along the lines of

```
targetContainer.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
    // coordinates of mouse relative to targetContainer:
    double mouseX = event.getX();
    double mouseY = event.getY();
    if (target.getBoundsInParent().contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
        System.out.println("Hit target");
    }
});
```

(This isn't quite the same as the code above, since the bounds represent the rectangular region containing the target, whereas a mouse event handler registered on the target itself will only be invoked if the mouse is pressed on the target itself - i.e. it takes the shape into account.)

The first version (registering the mouse listener with the target) is more natural and probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing:  


target.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
              @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAA");
        }

earlier, I was unable to get this to work, clicking would not print the line. I tried using your suggestion, which also didn't print anything upon clicking the circle. :( Would you like to see the class, or is there a common cause for this. Cheers, Lucio. http://pastebin.com/EWcpYhT8

Comment: Yes; edit your question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not the entire application, just a simple, complete, executable example that demonstrates what you are trying).

Comment: It would be better if you could post a standalone, executable example. I copied your code and commented out the parts that wouldn't work without external resources and classes that weren't provided, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to me. I just woke up and tried creating an MCVE. It turned out to be a productive process. I decided to  use root.getChildren().addAll(target);  instead of  Group root = new Group(RectangleMouseBox,target); and the clicking instantly detected from then on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question was to change the following:

```
    target = new Group(OuterRingTarget,OuterWhiteRingTarget,MiddleRingTarget,MiddleWhiteRingTarget,InnerRingTarget,BullseyeTarget);
    Group root = new Group(RectangleMouseBox,target);
```

to

```
    target = new Group(OuterRingTarget, OuterWhiteRingTarget, MiddleRingTarget, MiddleWhiteRingTarget, InnerRingTarget, BullseyeTarget);
    Group root = new Group(RectangleMouseBox);
    root.getChildren().addAll(target);
```